# How do I access to an address in memory with c#?

Tags: c#

How can read a value of a variable in memeory, as binary, which I have its pointer address for in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article shows how to use the Win32 `ReadProcessMemory` function to do it.  Note that using the `unsafe` keyword is not sufficient, as it does not give you the ability to specify an explicit memory location.

**How to write a Memory Scanner using C#**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sojaner_memory_scanner.aspx

To view the relevant code, you will need to download the project source, and examine the `MemoryScanner.cs` class.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Marshal.Read* functions like [Marshal.ReadInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eawzfdz5.aspx).  Cast the pointer value to an IntPtr and use helper methods in the Marshall class to get at the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use unsafe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6.aspx

Comment: You can pin an arbitrary memory location this way, but can you specify the exact memory location you want to pin?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `unsafe` keyword.  This allows you to access the memory directly, like in C++.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6.aspx